# C#.NET Oracle.ManagedDataAccess ConfigSchema.xsd

Tags: c#, .net, xml, oracle, xsd

I'm not able to find the config schema file (ConfigSchema.xsd) of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess for the itellisense in the application configuration file.

It supposed to be in ODP.NET Managed Driver Files but I cannot find it...

> ConfigSchema.xsd An XML schema file that defines the configuration section for ODP.NET, Managed Driver.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/installODPmd.htm

Answer (score 0):

After having installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015, it seems two schema files have been linked to my App.config file :

> Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd
>
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Configuration.Section.xsd

Both are stored in :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\xml\Schemas